# Sound not working in new 20.04 upgrade

Tags: sound, 20.04

i not play video because of sound not playing in new LTS update...

Comment: Some more details maybe helpful. Is this a new install? or an updated system (were you running 19.10? 18.04? or something else?) What program are you using to play videos, are any crash reports added in /var/crash/ ?  If you run the unspecified video program from terminal do you get any crash or problem details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really i dont know what happen, i make

```
sudo alsa force-reload && reboot
```

you can also install 
    `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

and in activities find pavucontrol and you can control dissapear devices

and working, really i dont know what happen, i test with card of pc and external monitor and tv

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a Dell Inspiron 1525. I tried all the solutions listed here on askubuntu.com and all over the web but of no use and finally to find that it is a bug in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS/kernel-5.4 (Focal kernel) where the internal sound card is not detected. The driver soc-skl is disabled by
default from kernel-5.4. Kernels 5.5, 5.6 all disabled this driver. Read the bug reports [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1869799) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061).

It affects many users. There is nothing much we can do until the kernels are fixed.

For me, the headphones and mic are working. For the time being, connecting the headphone jacks to external speakers solves the problem.